# Privacy, VPN and routers

Tags: router, vpn, privacy, ipv6, pptp

Ever since this ACTA push-up the things are starting to heat up around torrents and privacy.
I am using Tribler now, but this is not secure enough for me. Not enough privacy.

I've been using in the past a swedish VPN PPTP connection. What I observed is that, when the VPN connection was down, Internet traffic wasn't cut off, rather the downloads were continuing, this time with my real IP, wearing off my protection.

1st : How to enforce a VPN connection that will cut all traffic when down? That is, the moment the connection is down, all internet traffic should cease as if I'd pull the network plug out.

2nd: Is PPTP good enough or should I ask for SSTP or IKEV2 ?

3rd: Should I disable IPv6 ? Is VPN no longer private if I keep IPv6 active?

I 'heard some stuff' about dual vpn routers to be able to improve privacy; but nothing more about how to configure one for such a task.

4th: Is there any kind of "black box" hardware equipment that can be used in hiding IP, encrypting traffic and so on ?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I managed to find some answers...

For the first question, I had to program my own utility. I learned that there is a "routing table" , to which the VPN connection is added as destination 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 with its gateway and lower metric. However the internet connection has the same destination and mask, making it a backup when the VPN disconnects. The solution was to remove the internet route, so that there is no backup. Since the command "route delete 0.0.0.0" would remove both routes, it's necessary to follow with "route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 vpn_gateway metric vpn_metric". However, I keep the old route saved during session so that I could return to internet case VPN disconnects and doesn't want to come back. I experimented my own idea and I saw programs running out of internet after disconnecting the VPN.

For the 2nd question, I see a lot of people saying PPTP is too old and undeveloped for a long while.

For the 3rd question, there main source was [this post on torrentfreak](http://torrentfreak.com/huge-security-flaw-makes-vpns-useless-for-bittorrent-100617). I just found a Microsoft FixIT and disabled it. However, after visiting Ipredator FAQ page, I found that IPv6 was still enabled in the connection. Don't know how the hell was still enabled since I disabled IPv6 overall. I also disabled the protocol on the LAN and my internet PPTP connection as well.

For the 4th, no clue...

Hope this helps the occasional googler that wants to repair the VPN issue...

Comment: IPv6 offers the same privacy options IPv4 does.  Using VPN already encrypts your information there isn't a need for black box

Comment: Even if there was a "black box" that claimed to do all that, would you trust it?  Better to "roll your own."

Answer (score 1):

You should look into a project called I2p.  It is an encrypted tunneling protocol use to anonyomize your internet connection and is specifically engineered for use with torrents.  It can be configured as a proxy in your favorite torrent client and it also includes I2PSnark which will only download when it is connected to the I2P network.  It is built with speed in mind unlike TOR so it is therefore much more efficient in routing your traffic and hiding the source. This could be combined with your current vpn to add an additional layer of encryption and anonymity.

Comment: You should keep in mind that they know when you use ipsec, "they" being the ISP. I2P last time I checked was a nice idea, but not prime time.

Comment: This is interesting. It seems to work for magnet links; torrents, however, have to be i2p torrents.